# How to deduce the radius of convergence of a rational function on the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

What arguments are available to deduce that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of 
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3-1}{x-2}$$
centered at $x=0$ is 2, where $f$ is considered as a real function of a real variable?

Note: I am aware that the answer is the distance to the closest singularity, but I do not want an invocation of that fact. What arguments could you use to get to the result if you had forgotten this fact?

Observe that the series for $x^3-1$ (namely itself) has radius $\infty$, while the series for $(x-2)^{-1}$ has radius 2. [Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/multiplication-of-power-series-and-their-convergences) the radius of convergence of the product of two power series is at least the minimum of the radii of the factors, and [since](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_series_operator_is_multiplicative) Taylor series are multiplicative, we conclude that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ at $x=0$ is at least 2.

The harder part is showing it can't be more than 2. It is obvious that $f$ can't equal its Taylor series past 2 because of the discontinuity, but [this alone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893578/can-the-radius-of-analyticity-of-a-smooth-real-function-be-smaller-than-the-ra) does not imply that the Taylor series for $f$ can't converge past 2. The result follows, though, as soon as we show $f$ equals its Taylor series out to 2.

So far as I can see, there are two possibilities:

**1. argue by direct calculation**

This approach ignores the observations above; we simply compute. The Taylor series of the product $(x^3-1)(x-2)^{-1}$ is the product of the Taylor series of the factors,

$$(x^3-1)\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{8}+O(x^4)\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\sum_{k=3}^\infty\left(2^{-k-1}-2^{-k+2}\right)x^k$$

The ratio test shows this converges when $|x|<2$.

**2. argue using Cauchy's theorem on the expansion of a function in a power series in its domain of analyticity ([theorem 16.7 in Markushevich](https://books.google.com/books?id=mpdDAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&dq=markushevich%20complex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB3ru-tsbOAhWPsh4KHZjgDrYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=theorem%2016.7%20cauchy's%20theorem%20on%20the%20expansion%20of%20an%20analytic%20function&f=false))**

Since the corresponding complex function is differentiable in the disk $|z|<2$, Cauchy's theorem says it equals its Taylor series on that disk; hence the same is true for the real function $f$, which must therefore equal its Taylor series out to $x=2$. Since $f$ has an infinite discontinuity at $2$ but Taylor series are continuous, the series can't converge past 2.

> Are there other approaches that don't amount to these two in disguise? I'm curious whether I'm missing something.

Comment: ... nearest non-removable singularity, of course.

Comment: @hardmath: I misspoke. What I meant is I want the argument, not just an invocation of the fact.

Comment: Okay, the theorem says if the power series (say about zero, for simplicity) converges at $x=a$, then the function is absolutely convergenet (thus analytic) in the open disk of radius $a$ (about the origin).  So there are no non-removable singularities closer than the radius of convergence, ie. radius of convergence is at least the distance to non-removable singularity.  You want a proof that absolute convergence of a power series implies analyticity?

Comment: @hardmath: no. I already have an argument that the radius of convergence must be at least 2: see my 3rd paragraph. what I want is the rest of the argument, or another argument entirely, that is not simply an invocation of "a theorem says the answer is 2." as far as I can tell, Robert Israel's answer is just my second argument.

Comment: But this argument gives both directions, namely the radius of convergence cannot be greater than $2$, because any place where the power series converges at distance greater than $2$ gives absolute convergence with $|x|=2$.

Comment: @hardmath: sorry, I read too quickly. isn't the way to prove the theorem by way of my argument #2? the key is knowing that the function equals its Taylor series within the disk of convergence.

Comment: Sure, I will buy that your appeal to analyticity in argument #2 holds the key to proving radius of convergence = distance to nearest singularity.  I offered a Comment to help clarify what you would like to show.  Of course there are (for a rational function) ways to exhibit this radius of convergence more computationally and less abstractly.  E.g. we could show the region where the power series of $f(x)$ converges absolutely agrees with the region where that of $(x-2)^{-1}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @hardmath: regarding your "e.g.," that's exactly what I do in argument #1...

Comment: Okay, I had in mind to write $f(x) = p(x) + \frac{7}{x-2}$ where $p(x)$ is a 2nd degree polynomial.  Since absolute convergence allows us to rearrange terms in a series, and since $p(x)$ has an infinite radius of converges (because it is a finite "series"), the equality of the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ and $\frac{7}{x-2}$ is evident.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks, that is a slightly different take on the issue and helpful. I feel that my use of the word "heuristic" distracted everyone from the substance of the question.

Comment: It can certainly be argued that how we compute the radius of convergence of $1/(x-2)$ is the ratio test, but at least it is a pure geometric series and "ratio test" is something of a "by inspection" check.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a "heuristic".  The function $f(z) = \dfrac{z^3-1}{z-2}$ is analytic on the complex plane except for the singularity at $z=2$, which is a pole (note that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to 2$).  Therefore its Taylor series about $z=a$ has radius of convergence $|a-2|$.

Comment: Well, yes, but what I meant is I want the reasoning behind the "therefore." Isn't this just argument #2?

Comment: I am asking for the reasoning behind your similar answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/46830/23611), which Pete Clark also suggested it would be useful to give, in that context. I believe the reasoning proceeds by way of the theorem I cite in argument #2.

Comment: Yes, it is basically from Cauchy's theorems.

Answer (score 1):

Boring approach: $f(x)=P(x)+\frac{C}{x-2}$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial and $C$ a constant. The conclusion follows.
Another approach without mentioning poles(but uses the same idea): since the power series of $f(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ at least in $(0,2)$, it tends to infinity as $x\to 2$. Hence it cannot converge in an interval containing $2$. This shows its radius of convergence has to be $2$.

Comment: yes, thanks; hardmath mentioned this approach in the comments. I was missing the more elementary way of getting to the fact that $f(x)$ equals its Taylor series on $(0,2)$. this falls out of the argument using complex analysis, but it is also obvious from the real setting if we write the function as your sum.